# ManyToMany relations in symfony doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a Agency Entity
with a fields $owns

looks like

```html
      /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ShipType", inversedBy="owners")
     */
    protected $owns;
```

on ShipType Entity
i have

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Agency", mappedBy="owns")
 */
private $owners;
```

doctrine created a relations table for association between tables with agency_id and ship_type_id

i'm trying to get a form to work for assign each agency to a ship type ( owns )
im trying to achieve logging as an agency

so far i got

```
   public function gShips(Request $request): Response {
    $u = $this->getUser();
    $ag = new Agency();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChooseShipsType::class, $ag);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $a = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($a);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return $this->render('agency/sships.html.twig', [
        'adForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

and the form

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('ships', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:ShipType',
            'expanded'  => true,
            'multiple'  => true,
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Agency'
    ]);
}
```

the form is showing, but can't get it to persist because it's trying to create a new Agency, i can't figure out how to use the relation table between these two tables

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the constructor of your Agency class. Make sure it has the following:

```
$this->owns = new ArrayCollection();
```

And then, make sure you have an `addOwns()` method:

```
public function addOwns(ShipType $shipType) 
{
    $this->owns[] = $shipType;
}
```

And also a setter:

```
public function setOwns($owns)
{
    if ($owns instanceof ArrayCollection) {
        $this->owns = $owns;
    } else {
        if (!$this->owns->contains($owns)) {
            $this->owns[] = $owns;
        }
        $this->owns;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Also, make sure you have the getter with the default content. That should do.

PS: You shouldn't name your properties as verbs though, but that's another thing.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer because the former had some logical errors. `is_array` method cannot be called on `ArrayCollection`. Sorry!